# Mongodb modifying attribute when queried from python script

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

In my application, I have few entries in mongodb which is inserted/modified by Java/PhP/Python.

My issue is when I am querying for a document, the mongo shell returns the correct output, but the same query, when executed through python(pymongo) script, 1 particular value(id) to replaced to 0.

I can't share the actual data, consider the sample below:

Mongoshell

> Query: `db.collection_A.find({"_id": "abc"})`

Output from mongoshell:

```
{
  "_id": "abc",
  "entries": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "otherID": 11,
      "Name": "abc",
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "otherID": 22,
      "Name": "xyz",
    }
  ]
}
```

Python script:

```
import pymongo

fileid = "abc"
cursor = db.collection_A.find_one({"_id": fileid})
print cursor
```

Output from python script:

```
{
  "_id": "abc",
  "entries": [
    {
      "id": 0,
      "otherID": 11,
      "Name": "abc",
    },
    {
      "id": 0,
      "otherID": 22,
      "Name": "xyz",
    }
  ]
}
```

Why is this happening? How so I fix it?

Comment: not enough information here, show some code

Comment: updated the question

Comment: you might need to use the show_record_id flag which is by default set to False

Comment: How does showRecordId affect the data which is already present in the db?

Comment: I was not aware that the nested id was also present in the dB, I assumed it was a self generated id by the client to enumerate results